# Can GET, PUT and PATCH be replaced with POST HTTP method?

Tags: rest, http, restful-url

POST , PUT, PATCH and GET are all different. Idempotent  and safety being the key difference makers. 
While writing RESTFul APIs , I encountered guidelines on when and where to use one of the HTTP methods. Since I am using Java for the back-end implementation, I can control the behavior of the HTTP methods on the persistent data. 
For example , GET v1/book/{id} can be replaced with POST v1/book (with "id" in body) now with that id I can perform a query on db , fetching that particular book. (assuming book with that id already exists). 
Similarly , I can achieve the workings of PATCH and PUT with POST itself.

Now, coming to the question , why don't we just use POST instead of GET , PUT and PATCH almost every time, ALMOST, when we can control the idempotent and safety behavior in the back-end?

Or , Is it just a guideline mentioned in RESTFul docs somewhere or stated by Roy fielding and we all are blindly following? Even if the guidelines are so what is the major idea behind them?

https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/

https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html

https://www.keycdn.com/support/put-vs-post

Above resources just mention either what does all the methods do or their differences. Articles mention the workings as if they were some guidelines , none of the docs online speak about the reason behind them.

None of them says , what if I used POST instead of PUT, PATCH and GET, what would be the side-effects? (as I can control their behaviors in the back-end)

Answer (score 1):

Http methods are designed in the way that each method holds some responsibility. I will say that REST are the standards which are conventions and not the obligation. The convention doesn't stress us to follow the rules but they are designed for our code betterment. You can tweak the things and can use them in your way but that would be a bad idea. Like in this case if you are performing all the three actions with one method it would create great confusion in code (As the simple definition of POST is to create an object and that is what understood by everyone) and also degrade our coding standards.
I strongly discourage to replace three methods with one.

Answer (score 0):

If you do that, you can't say you are "writing RESTFul APIs".
Whoever knows the RESTFul standard, will be confused about the behaviour of your apis.
If you fit the standard, then you will have an easier life.

After all, you have no real benefit in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a transport protocol which as its name suggest is responsible for transfering data such as files or db entries across the wire to or from a remote system. In version 0.9 you basically only had the `GET` operation at your disposal while in HTTP 1.0 almost all of the current operations were added to the spec.

Each of these methods fulfills its own purpose. `POST` i.e. does process the payload according to the server's own semantics, whatever they will be. In theory it could be used therefore for retrieving, updating or removing content. Though, to a client it is basically unclear what a server actually does with the payload. There is no guarantee whether invoking a URI with that method is safe (the remote resource being altered) or not. Think of a crawler that is just invoking any URIs it finds and one of the links is an order link or a link where you perform a payment process. Do you really want a crawler to trigger one of your processes? The spec is rather clear that if something like that happens, the client must not made accountable for that. So, if a crawler ordered 10k products as one of your links, did trigger such a process, and the products are created in that process, you can't claim refund from the crawler's maintainer.

In additon to that, a response from a `GET` operation is cacheable by default. So if you invoke the same resource twice in a certain amount of time, chances are that the resource does not need to be fetched again a second (third, ...) time as it can be reused from the cache. This can reduce the load on the server quite significantly if used propperly.

As you've mentioned Fielding and REST. REST is an architectural style which you should use if you have plenty of different clients connecting to your services that are furthermore not under your control. Plenty of so-called REST APIs aren't adhering to REST as they follow a more simple and pragmatic RPC approach with external documentations such as Swagger and similar. RESTs main focus is on the decoupling of clients from servers which allow the latters to evolve freely without having to fear breaking clients. Clients on the other hand get more robust to changes.

Fielding only added [few constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) a REST architecture has to adhere to. One of them is [support for caching](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4). Though Fielding later on wrote a well-cited [blog-post](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) where he explains what API designers have to consider before calling their API REST. True decoupling can only occur if all of the constraints are followed strictly. If only one clients violates these premises it won't benefit from REST at all.

The main premise in REST is (and should always be): Server teaches clients what they need and clients only use what they are served with. In the browsable Web, the big cousin of REST, a server will teach a client i.e. on what data the server expects via Web Forms through HTML and links are annotated with link-relation names to give the browser some hints on when to invoke that URI. On a Web page a trash bin icon may indicate a delition while a pencil icon may indicate an edit link. Such visual hints are also called [affordacne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817). Such visual hints may not be applicable in machine to machine communication though such affordances may hint on other things they may provide. Think of a stylesheet that is annotated with `preload`. In HTTP 2 i.e. such a resource could be attempted to be pushed by the server or in HTTP 1.1 the browser could alread load that stylesheet while the page is still parsed to speed things up. In order to gain whitespread knowledge of those meanings, such values should be standardized at [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml). Through [custom extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2) or certain [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values) such as [dublin core](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/) or the like you may add new relation names that are too specific for common cases but are common to the domain itself.

The same holds true for [media-types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) client and server negotiate about. A general applicable media-type will probably reach wider acceptance than a tailor-made one that is only usable by a single company. The main aim here is to reach a point where the same media-type can be reused for various areas and APIs. REST vision is to have a minimal amount of clients that are able to interact with a plethora of servers or APIs, similar to a browser that is able to interact with almost all Web sites.

Your ultimate goal in REST is that a user is [following an interaction protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=420) you've set up, which could be something similar to following an order process or playing a text game or what not. By giving a client choices it will progress through a certain process which can easily be depicted as state machine. It is following a kind of application-driven protocol by following URIs that caught the clients attention and by returning data that was taught through a form like representation. As, more or less, only standardized representation formats should be used, there is no need for out-of-band information on how to interact with the API necessary.

In reality though, plenty of enterprises don't really care about long-lasting APIs that are free to evolve over the years but in short-term success stories. They usually also don't care that much whether they use the propper HTTP operations at all or stay in bounds with the HTTP spec (i.e. sending payloads with HTTP `GET` requesst). Their primary intent is to get the job done. Therefore pragmatism usually wins over design and as such plenty of developers follow the way of short success and have to adept their work later on, which is often cumbersome as the API is now the driving factor of their business and therefore they can't change it easily without having to revampt the whole design.

> ... why don't we just use POST instead of GET , PUT and PATCH almost every time, ALMOST, when we can control the idempotent and safety behavior in the back-end?

A server may know that a request is idempotent, but the client does not. Properties such as `safe` and `idempotency` are promisses to the client. Whether the server satisfies these or not is a different story. How should a client know whether a sent payment request reached the server and the response just got lost or the initial request didn't make it to the server at all in case of a temporary connection issue? A `PUT` requests does guarante idempotency. I.e. you don't want to order the same things twice if you resubmit the same request again in case of a network issue. While the same request could also be sent via `POST` and the server being smart enough to not process it again, the client doesn't know the server's behavior unless it is externally documented somehwere, which violates REST principles again also somehow. So, to state it differently, such properties are more or less promisses to the client, less to the server.